# Facebook iOS SDK Dialog issue Text Input

Tags: facebook, ios4, textbox, user-input

I'm building a Facebook app that calls a Facebook dialog box to allow users to share a post.

Using the facebook documentation, a call to the facebook object:

```
[appDelegate.facebook dialog:@"feed" andDelegate:self];
```

opens the dialog box I need.  However, the keyboard for user input doesn't popup, and all I can do is post a blank post up on my wall.  Has anyone else encountered this?

Comment: I'm going to assume that you have to create a form for a user to fill, and then submit that as the @message" parameter for the post.  Let me know if anyone has another solution.  Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you ever figure out how to resolve this issue? I'm seeing the same thing. I'm using the three20 framework in addition to the Facebook SDK - maybe that has something to do with it?

**Update:**

I figured out the issue I was seeing, and hopefully this will help you.

The problem was that I didn't call [self.window makeKeyAndVisible] in application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:. Once I added that call the keyboard started appearing in the FBDialog. Check out this post: [Keyboard not Appearing when Tapping Text Box in UIWebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6312680/keyboard-not-appearing-when-tapping-text-box-in-uiwebview)

Comment: I am calling that. My facebook keyboard appears the first time, but not after that.